# How to get all attributes with same tag name with xmllint xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, xmllint

Sample xml-

```
<xml>
<Tag name="attr1"></Tag>
<Tag name="attr2"></Tag>
<Tag name="attr2"></Tag>
</xml>
```

How can I get values of all the attributes with xmllint, like this-

```
attr1
attr2
attr3
```

I can only use xmllint. I have tried this-

```
xmllint --xpath 'string(//Tag/@name)'
```

But this only returns first match.

Comment: The second and third tags in the list above both have `"attr2"` as the name. Is this a typo? It looks like the third should be `"attr3"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `string()` will only give you the first match in XPath 1.0. If you remove `string()` you'll get all three attributes, but you'd have to post-process them to get only the values. I suppose this will depend on how you're running xmllint (what os/shell/etc).

Something like (tested with bash in cygwin)...

```sh
attrs=$(xmllint --xpath "//Tag/@name" sample.xml)
echo $attrs | sed 's/\s*name="\([^"]*\)"/\1\n/g'
```

Another option is to first get a count of how many `Tag` elements and then call xmllint that many times with a positional predicate on `Tag`.

Something like (tested with bash in cygwin)...

```sh
count=$(xmllint --xpath "count(//Tag)" sample.xml)

if [[ $count != 0 ]]; then
    for ((i=1; i<=$count; i++)); do
       echo $(xmllint --xpath "string(//Tag[$i]/@name)" sample.xml)
    done
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter and more consice solution with cut :

```
echo "$pagesource" | xmllint --html --xpath "/html/body/div/a/@href" - | cut -d '"' -f 2
```

Explanation :

```
echo "$pagesource" | xmllint --html --xpath "/html/body/div/a/@href"
```

Will return :

```
href="site1"
href="site2"
href="site3"
```

You simply use `cut` and set `"` as the delimiter to select the sites :

```
site1
site2
site3
```